# WebStorm do not inspect part of underscore template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, phpstorm, webstorm

I have the following template in bootstrap.js file:

[image]

As you can see, WebStorm shows errors because it can't parse the source correctly.

I'm wondering if there is any way:

1. to completely disable inspection on that particular region in the file
2. wrap it in the comments and specify for the template engine to remove these comments when rendering template.

Comment: 1) Nope. It's either correctly parsed or treated as an error. Errors from low level parser cannot be suppressed (only Inspections can, which are higher level) 2) Don't think so as well. **In general:** https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-679 (maybe you will some workarounds in comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebStorm provides no support for UnderscoreJS ([WEB-679](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-679)). But, as the syntax looks similar to EJS, you can try the following:

- associate the .js files with embedded template syntax with EJS file type, by adding `<file_name>.js` as a pattern there
- when associating, choose 'javascript' as template data language for these files

[image]

Comment: great, thanks a lot, that worked! fantastic solution)